# Netty 4: how to manually invoke handlers?

Tags: java, netty

The situation: `DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder extends ByteToMessageDecoder`, and `ByteToMessageDecoder` does keep the unprocessed bytes in a `ByteBuf` called `cumulation`.
I'd like to manually call this handler inside another handler to empty this `cumulation` `ByteBuf`.

What I tried:

```
DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder frameDecoder = (DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder) inboundChannel.pipeline().get("frameDecoder");
frameDecoder.channelRead(ctx, Unpooled.EMPTY_BUFFER);
```

The problem: What I tried doesn't work because there's no next handler so Netty tells me that the bytes are lost:

> Discarded inbound message UnpooledHeapByteBuf(ridx: 0, widx: 57, cap:
>   57) that reached at the tail of the pipeline. Please check your
>   pipeline configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wrap your handler in a EmbeddedChannel and use writeInbound() and readInbound(). Check our unit tests for usage examples and also the javadocs.

Comment: I can't reuse the DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder in the EmbeddedChannel as it's not @Sharable, nor can I retrieve the data that's "stuck" in its internal buffer (cumulation). singleDecode was set to true, that's why there are(!) actually enough bytes left to be handled (which weren't handled because only 1 frame was handled). There's no more data to read from the channel, that's why I want to manually perform the handling...

Comment: I figured it out. If interested you can check my answer. My test client which creates 3k connections to the server that uses that code sometimes report me that 1-20/3k connections didn't send back the correct amount of replies (500 per client) but that's probably another issue (= to be debugged).

Answer (score 0):

Norman put me on the right track but here's what I needed to do in my case:

```
PublicCumulationDelimiterBasedFrameDecoder frameDecoder = (PublicCumulationDelimiterBasedFrameDecoder) cp.get("frameDecoder");

ByteBuf bytesNotProcessed = frameDecoder.internalBuffer();

if (bytesNotProcessed != Unpooled.EMPTY_BUFFER) {                                   PublicCumulationDelimiterBasedFrameDecoder tmpDelimiterBasedFrameDecoder = new PublicCumulationDelimiterBasedFrameDecoder(2048, false, true, Unpooled.wrappedBuffer(new byte[] { 0x03 }));

    EmbeddedChannel ec = new EmbeddedChannel(tmpDelimiterBasedFrameDecoder, ... other handlers...);

    ByteBuf wrapper = Unpooled.buffer();
    wrapper.writeBytes(bytesNotProcessed);

    ec.writeInbound(wrapper);// make it process the bytes

    // put the remaining bytes (if any) back into the original buffer
    bytesNotProcessed.clear();
    bytesNotProcessed.writeBytes(tmpDelimiterBasedFrameDecoder.internalBuffer());
}
```

where `PublicCumulationDelimiterBasedFrameDecoder` is just this:

```
public class PublicCumulationDelimiterBasedFrameDecoder extends DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder {

    public PublicCumulationDelimiterBasedFrameDecoder(int maxFrameLength, boolean stripDelimiter, boolean failFast, ByteBuf delimiter) {
        super(maxFrameLength, stripDelimiter, failFast, delimiter);
    }

    public ByteBuf internalBuffer() {
        return super.internalBuffer();
    }
}
```